# Elliptic Integral-ish?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

I'm trying to solve this integral 
$\int (1-\cos(\theta))^{2}\sqrt{1-k^{2}cos(\theta)^{2}} \mathrm{d}\theta$

I think it's some kind of elliptic integral but i can't integrate.

Comment: It is indeed an elliptic integral: [https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(1-cos+x)%5E2*sqrt(1-k%5E2*cos%5E2+x)+dx](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(1-cos+x)%5E2*sqrt(1-k%5E2*cos%5E2+x)+dx). Why are you interested in this particular integral?

Comment: @MisterRiemann Interesting... When I put this in Wolfram|Alpha  it didn't give a result. I'm trying to find the deflection of a point on an elliptical arch using Castigliano's 2nd theorem. (1-cos(x))² term comes from moment equation.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica can integrate this. The code

```
Integrate[(1 - Cos[t])^2 Sqrt[1 - m Cos[t]^2], t] // FullSimplify // InputForm
```

returns

```
-(-12*(-1 + m)*Sqrt[m]*ArcTanh[(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[m]*Sin[t])/
  Sqrt[2 - m - m*Cos[2*t]]]*Sqrt[2 - m - m*Cos[2*t]] +
4*(-1 + m)*(-1 + 5*m)*Sqrt[(-2 + m + m*Cos[2*t])/(-1 + m)]*
   EllipticE[t, m/(-1 + m)] +
4*(-1 + m)*Sqrt[(-2 + m + m*Cos[2*t])/
  (-1 + m)]*EllipticF[t, m/(-1 + m)] +
Sqrt[2]*m*(-2 + m + m*Cos[2*t])*(-6*Sin[t] + Sin[2*t])) /
  (12*m*Sqrt[2 - m - m*Cos[2*t]])
```

which can be written as $\, (A_1+A_2+A_3)/B\,$ where
$\, u := m\cos(2t)+m-2\,$

$$ A_1 := -12 (1-m) \sqrt{m} \sqrt{u} \tan^{-1}
\left(\frac{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{m} \sin (t)}{\sqrt{u}}\right), $$
$$ A_2 := -\frac{u \left(4 F\left(t\left|\frac{m}{m-1}\right.\right)+4 (5 m-1)
   E\left(t\left|\frac{m}{m-1}\right.\right)\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{u}{m-1}}}, $$
$$ A_3 := -\sqrt{2} m u (\sin (2 t)-6 \sin (t)),\quad
   B := 12m\sqrt{-u}. $$